# How to use limit the results returned from SQL Server using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have database as below

```
CREATE DATABASE Test2;

CREATE TABLE table1
(
    name nvarchar(50),
    year int,
    total1 int,
    total2 int
);

INSERT INTO table1 (name, year, total1,total2)
VALUES ('a', 2020, 25,3);
INSERT INTO table1 (name, year, total1,total2)
VALUES ('b', 2018, 33,4);
INSERT INTO table1 (name, year, total1,total2)
VALUES ('c', 2020, 10,3);
INSERT INTO table1 (name, year, total1,total2)
VALUES ('b', 2018, 7,2);
INSERT INTO table1 (name, year, total1,total2)
VALUES ('a', 2020, 20,6);
```

I want to limit the results returned from SQL Server (take 2nd row and 3rd row) with this code

```
select 
    *
from
    (select 
         year, name, 
         sum(total1) as "sum_Total1", 
         sum(total2) as "sum_Total2", 
         round((cast(isnull(sum(total2), 0) as float)) / (cast(sum(total1) as float)), 3) as "sum_Total2/sum_Total1", 
         row_number() over (order by round((cast(isnull(sum(total2), 0) as float)) / (cast(sum(total1) as float)), 3) asc) as no
     from 
         Table_1
     group by 
         name, year
     order by 
         round((cast(isnull(sum(total2), 0) as float)) * 100 / (cast(sum(total1) as float)), 3) asc) a
where 
    a.no > 1 and a.no < 3
```

SQL Server return an error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually since you have already used the `Order By` in this line `ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY ROUND` you don't need to use it again in your inner query after grouping. So all that you need to do is removing the unnecessary order by after your group by keyword.

Also FYI, I can see that you've queried from `Table_1` while your table name is `table1`, so you need to fix it as well.

Answer (score 1):

there are two issues:

1. You are not using the same table which you created.
2. to get the 2nd and 3rd row, you'll need to change the condition a.no < 3 to a.no <= 3

there is no use of `order by` clause as we have `no`.

Finally:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT year, 
           name, 
           SUM(total1) AS "sum_Total1", 
           SUM(total2) AS "sum_Total2", 
           ROUND((CAST(ISNULL(SUM(total2), 0) AS FLOAT)) / (CAST(SUM(total1) AS FLOAT)), 3) AS "sum_Total2/sum_Total1", 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
           ORDER BY ROUND((CAST(ISNULL(SUM(total2), 0) AS FLOAT)) / (CAST(SUM(total1) AS FLOAT)), 3) ASC) AS no
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY name, 
             year
    --ORDER BY ROUND((CAST(ISNULL(SUM(total2), 0) AS FLOAT)) * 100 / (CAST(SUM(total1) AS FLOAT)), 3) ASC
) a
WHERE a.no > 1
      AND a.no <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the order by outside your subquery:

```
select * 
from
(
select year ,name,
sum(total1) as "sum_Total1", 
SUM(total2) as "sum_Total2", 
ROUND((CAST(ISNULL(sum(total2),0) as float))/ 
      (CAST(sum(total1) as float)),3) as "sum_Total2/sum_Total1", 
ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY 
ROUND((CAST(ISNULL(sum(total2),0) as float))/ (CAST(sum(total1) as float)),3) ASC )  as no
from Table1
group by name, year
) a
where a.no > 1 and a.no < 4
order by no;
```